# Angular: I can get the object from Service, but it seems I did not assign an object properly

Tags: angular, observable

**Component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ItemsService } from '../items.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Item } from '../item.model';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-customer',
  templateUrl: './customer-detail.component.html',
  // styleUrls: ['./customers-table.component.css'],
  providers: [ItemsService],
})
export class CustomerDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  customer: Item;
  constructor(private _itemsService: ItemsService, private route: 
ActivatedRoute) {
  }

ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.getDataFromService().subscribe(data => 
console.log(data)));
    this.getDataFromService().subscribe(data => this.customer = data);
    console.log(this.customer);
  }

  public getDataFromService() {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    const paraid: string = String(id);
    return this._itemsService.getItem(paraid);
  }

}
```

**Service:**

```
@Injectable()
export class ItemsService {

  private BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/api/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  // Uses http.get() to load data from a single API endpoint
  getItem(id: String): Observable<Item> {
    console.log('getItem: ' + id);
    return this.http.get<Item>(`${this.BASE_URL + id}`);
  }
```

**From the console log I've got this:**

```
Subscriber {closed: false, _parent: null, _parents: null, 
_subscriptions: Array(1), syncErrorValue: null, …}

[{…}]
0
:
{CustomerID: 1000, FirstName: "Suzanne", LastName: "Jones", BirthDate: 
"1999-01-01"}
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array(0)
```

---

I have an item to fetched from API endpoint, which will get the item by SQL query from the database, I have succeeded to get the data as I can console.log(data).
but I can't console.log(this.customer), did I do something wrong in data => this.customer = data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you are not calling the method from the service, you need to use

```
this._itemsService.getDataFromService()
```

and You are getting data from an API asynchronously and trying to access it before the response, place the console.log inside the subscribe,

```
this._itemsService.getDataFromService().subscribe((data) =>  { 
   console.log(data)
   this.customer = data;
   console.log(this.customer);
});
```

Comment: thank you, I can console.log(this.customer) now. I have one more 
I tried to do the 2-way binding, and assign name = this.customer.firstName; and in the html file, I put <h1>{{name}}</h1>. However, I have got the error (core.js:1673 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined), do you know why it happened in my case?

Comment: you can just do {{customer?.firstName}}

Comment: could it because in the database, the column name is FirstName, and in Angular, I set the interface firstName?

Comment: cannot be, can you post what you get when you do console.log(JSON.stringify(this.customer));

Comment: did it fix your issue /

Comment: [{"customerID":1000,"firstName":"Suzanne","lastName":"Jones","dateOfBirth":"1999-01-01"}] it is what I have got

Comment: dude its an array. so you need {{customer[0]?.firstName}

Comment: thanks, it works. Can I ask why the function will return to the array?

Answer (score 0):

OffCourse you will not get data in to your console.

because it will take time to fetch data and when you subscribe your function, it will go to fetch data, your outside `console` will be called.

Use `settimeout(()=> {}, 1000)` like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.getDataFromService().subscribe(data => 
console.log(data)));
    this.getDataFromService().subscribe(data => this.customer = data);
settimeout(()=> {  console.log(this.customer); }, 1000);
  }
```